# Compiling Wurst Client 1.12 in Eclipse

Tags: java, git, minecraft

I've been trying to compile Wurst but the minecraft patch always fails and yes I could do it manually, but I would rather find a way to fix it so it works automagically as supposed, it might help other people as well.

My steps were running mcp and let it do it's thing, then I cloned wurst and put the mcp's source/minecraft to wurst's root directory with name mc as in instructions
the script of initialize ran, but I noticed few errors:

> 

```
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/Minecraft.java:603
error: net/minecraft/client/Minecraft.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiButton.java:73
error: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiButton.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiDisconnected.java:13
error: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiDisconnected.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiIngame.java:366
error: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiIngame.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiIngameMenu.java:1
error: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiIngameMenu.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiMultiplayer.java:190
error: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiMultiplayer.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiScreenBook.java:66
error: net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiScreenBook.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/gui/ServerListEntryNormal.java:87
error: net/minecraft/client/gui/ServerListEntryNormal.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/gui/inventory/GuiChest.java:30
error: net/minecraft/client/gui/inventory/GuiChest.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/multiplayer/ServerList.java:24
error: net/minecraft/client/multiplayer/ServerList.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/network/NetHandlerPlayClient.java:885
error: net/minecraft/client/network/NetHandlerPlayClient.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/network/NetworkPlayerInfo.java:53
error: net/minecraft/client/network/NetworkPlayerInfo.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/renderer/BlockModelRenderer.java:73
error: net/minecraft/client/renderer/BlockModelRenderer.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.java:683
error: net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/renderer/InventoryEffectRenderer.java:18
error: net/minecraft/client/renderer/InventoryEffectRenderer.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/renderer/entity/RenderLivingBase.java:234
error: net/minecraft/client/renderer/entity/RenderLivingBase.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/client/resources/SkinManager.java:136
error: net/minecraft/client/resources/SkinManager.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/entity/Entity.java:790
error: net/minecraft/entity/Entity.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/entity/EntityLivingBase.java:2007
error: net/minecraft/entity/EntityLivingBase.java: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: net/minecraft/network/play/INetHandlerPlayClient.java:252
error: net/minecraft/network/play/INetHandlerPlayClient.java: patch does not apply
```

The Wurst github dir that I cloned: 
[Wurst-MC-1.12](https://github.com/Wurst-Imperium/Wurst-MC-1.12)

The guide I kinda followed: [Guide](https://github.com/scriptinator/Wurst-Wiki/blob/master/Debugging-Wurst-in-Eclipse.md)

And I noticed that actually none of the patch did apply. :(
Has anyone done this and succeeded? Thank you in advance!

UPD1: I tried this way instead of the provided wurst patch .bat:
      git apply --reject --whitespace=fix ..\patch\minecraft.patch
And I got kind of a result. Some files got patched, but some still returned errors related to whitespaces

Comment: Please directly open an issue on the Wurst github instead, you'll recieve far better support there than here

Comment: @Frontear I am not sure this is possible there as I don't see the issues button :( I think they disbaled issues for Wurst